# Pop Up Marker not Showing if Marker has been clicked

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a database that stores lat/long and display it automatically on my map. but my code is only showing the marker and when i click it there is NO pop up showing.

Heres my Code

```
function getInfo() { 
        $.getJSON("get.php", function (data) { 
          for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
            var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
            var marker = new L.Marker(location).addTo(map).bindPopup("Testing Pop Up");


             } 
        }); 
      }
```

how can i achieve it

Comment: Do you see the markers you're adding or nothing?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely! Actually i have some textboxes and i will right some data on it and save it on database but for now i only save the lat/long in database and showing a default marker and test pop up for example. Only the marker is showing when i click it many times no pop up is showing.

Comment: Still now I cant figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Bind the pop up before adding it to the map. Currently, it's adding it to the map prior to it knowing the pop up exists. Try this instead.

`var marker = new L.Marker(location).bindPopup("Testing Pop Up").addTo("map");`

If you wanted, you could also split it up into two lines, but it's all about personal preference.

```
var marker = new L.Marker(location).bindPopup("Testing Pop Up");

marker.addTo("map");
```